# Selecting last day of every month?

Tags: mysql, datetime, aggregate-functions

I have the following data in MySQL:

```
+------------+-------+
| myDATE     | delta |
+------------+-------+
| 2015-08-29 |    12 |
| 2015-08-30 |    12 |
| 2015-08-31 |    10 |
| 2015-09-01 |     0 |
| 2015-09-02 |  0.15 |
+------------+-------+
```

I want to run a query that will select the last day of each month and show the data. I thought I had it working but its not showing yesterdays data.

```
select mydate, delta from data group by date_format(mydate, '%Y-%m');
```

Results in:

```
+------------+-------+
| mydate     | delta |
+------------+-------+
| 2015-08-29 |    12 |
| 2015-09-01 |     0 |
+------------+-------+
```

What am I missing?

I'm looking for it to return this: (ie. The last day of each month on record)

```
+------------+-------+
| myDATE     | delta |
+------------+-------+
| 2015-08-31 |    10 |
| 2015-09-02 |  0.15 |
+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select last_day(mydate), sum(delta) from data group by last_day(mydate)
```

last_day is a function which returns the last day of the month the given date

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day

to answer the updated question

```
select data.`myDate`, data.delta from data inner join
(select max(`myDate`) myDate from data group by date_format(mydate, '%Y-%m')) a
on a.myDate = data.myDate
```

Comment: Thanks, not quite what I'm looking for. I've updated the OP to be more clear.

Comment: Getting a syntax error on the above - I think its because a ) is missing. Tried putting it in few places but no luck :(

Comment: Hmm - now its giving Unknown column 'a.myDate' in 'on clause'

Comment: Sorry try that now. I'm not at a computer so it's hard to test